# Do the usual rules of necromancy apply on the trilogy?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, necromancer-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reviving old questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20524/reviving-old-questions)

Is it okay to add a new answer to an old question?

Usually it's looked down upon in other forums and sites. But Stack Overflow is a different beast.

And if a question has an accepted answer, does that factor in the [Necromancer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer)?

Comment: What are the usual rules of necromancy anyway? Don't you just need a dead body?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20524/reviving-old-questions

Comment: The question in the title and the first question in the text is the same but with inverted sense.  The currently most accepted answer states "Yes".  Please fix the question to ask only one question.

Comment: @Teddy Edit was only to fix up the language, not to remove all of the questions the asker posted in spirit. Just because one part of the question has been answered isn't a reason to edit out the other lines to fit the answers better. When Pateras owns the question again, he can edit it out if he so wishes.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say, yes, it is a good thing (in fact there's even a [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer) for it). I think generally the philosophy is that all improvement to any question/answer over time is viewed as a good thing. As you say, SO isn't your typical forum, its more of a cross between a forum & a wiki.

Answer (score 4):

If you feel you can provide a better answer than is already posted, or bring something further to the discussion, then yes you are welcome to post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Having answers to questions is always a good thing. If I'd posted a question and got an answer after a long time, I certainly wouldn't mind.